# How to discover if a transaction is frequently aborting?

Tags: haskell, ghc, stm

I'm trying to debug a program that uses STM. The ThreadScope readings is pointing out a very high CPU activity as you can see here:

[image]

So I'm trying to find out if this is happening due to a transaction that frequently aborts. The first thing that I thought was using something like this to test:

```
atomically $ do
  someWork 
  ...
`orElse` do
  unsafeIOToSTM $ traceEventIO "transaction aborted!"
  retry
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct or if this is the best approach to debugging in an STM scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: That would have been my approach as well.

Comment: What results did you get from this approach?

Comment: There are no traces. If this approach is correct, no transaction is aborting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [stm-stats](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-stats) package. It provides `trackSTM` that you should use instead of `atomically`, and `dumpSTMStats :: IO ()` that will provide something like this:

```
STM transaction statistics (2011-10-09 12:28:37.188951 UTC):
Transaction     Commits    Retries      Ratio
_anonymous_           1          0       0.00
reader                1         23      23.00
writer               23          0       0.00
```

(Transaction names will be generated automatically, but there's helpers to set your own.)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay to respond. It seems that this package is not updated for a long time. I'll take a look how they check for retries. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about lack of updates: 1) Joachim, the maintainer, is well-known in the community; 2) the package is in Stackage LTS, which means it at least builds.

Comment: Just had some time to test `stm-stats` and it worked perfectly! The problem was indeed a transaction frequently aborting. Thank you!